# How to include INF driver install into VS Installer project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, installation, driver, setup-deployment

I use a Setup and Deploy project in Visual Studio 2008 to install my c# project.

I have a USB driver that i can manually install by right clicking the .inf file and choosing Install.

I think that if i had a .exe to install the driver, i could probably put it under Custom Actions.  I'm not even sure where to start to make my own .exe, let alone if it would work.

I'm fairly new at this, having taught myself C# and learned how to make an installer through trial and error. I usually get by using trusty Google or this forum but i have trouble finding the information on my own this time.

Please help or point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 3):

You can use run [devcon.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) from a custom action to perform in the installation.

Here is some [sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff541193%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) from the Windows Device Driver Kit demonstrating devcon.exe's APIs... but it's probably easier to use the command-line functions.

Comment: First off, thank you for your answer.  I skimmed through both your links and downloaded the .exe.  Not quite sure where to put in those command lines though... do you know how i can use devcon with my installer?

Comment: Sure... first you'd want to include DEVCON.EXE in your project's files if it is not found on the target system, then [create a Custom Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28VS.80%29.aspx) that runs the command-line to do the INF install. (Be sure to schedule the Custom Action to run *after* the files are installed!)

Comment: Ok, i tried this: Added devcon to custom actions/Commit. In arguments property i put "install ftdiport.inf" But i get a non-descriptive error during the installation. Will keep fiddling but if you see anything wrong with this can you let me know?

Comment: But devcon is not redistributable. :-(

Answer (score 2):

I am working on exactly the same problem that you are working on.  Please see my post:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/89c996c4-881b-47f0-815d-cf14135daf88/

I will let you know as soon as mine working.  Please let me know as soon as yours working.

Thanks,

Trammy

Comment: Oh thank you Trammy, i'll keep an eye on your thread as well. :)

Comment: It's been a few years--were you able to get this working?